# The program is crashing not loading the collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have have the sign in button that is leading to home page collection view . the program is crashing while loading the home page collection view .Here is the code for home page collection view .

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController ,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating{

    var items = [Food]()
    var filtered = [Food]()
    var searchActive : Bool = false
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    // var items = ["ASIAN","SEAFOOD","SUSHI","CAFE","Los Angeles","Austin","Seattle"]


    @IBOutlet var collectionViewController: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // imageViewArray=[#imageLiteral(resourceName: "food18") ,#imageLiteral(resourceName: "food19"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "food20"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "food21"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "food22"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "food23"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "food24")]

        self.items.append(Food(title: "View Appointment",    image: UIImage(named: "view appointments@1x.png")))
        self.items.append(Food(title: "Medical Chart",  image:UIImage(named: "medical chart@1x.png")))
        self.items.append(Food(title: "Task",    image:UIImage(named: "tasks@2x.png")))
        self.items.append(Food(title: "Referrals",     image:UIImage(named: "referrals@2x.png")))
        self.items.append(Food(title: "Profile", image:UIImage(named: "profile@2x.png")))
        self.items.append(Food(title: "Wallet",   image:UIImage(named: "wallet@2x.png")))

        collectionViewController.dataSource=self
        collectionViewController.delegate=self

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for tools and resources"
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchActive {
            return filtered.count
        }
        else
        {
            return items.count    //return number of rows in section
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesCollectionViewCell

        //configureCell(cell: cell as! toolCollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
        cell.imageViewCell=cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        if searchActive {
            cell.imageViewCell.image = self.filtered[indexPath.row].image
            cell.categoriesTitleLbl.text =  self.filtered[indexPath.row].title
        } else {
            cell.imageViewCell.image = self.items[indexPath.row].image
            cell.categoriesTitleLbl.text =  self.items[indexPath.row].title
        }
        return cell      //return your cell
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        guard let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text else {
            return
        }

        filtered = items.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
            if let title = item.title {
                return title.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased())
            } else {
                return false
            }
        })

        collectionViewController.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true
        collectionViewController.reloadData()
    }


    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false
        collectionViewController.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        if !searchActive {
            searchActive = true
            collectionViewController.reloadData()
        }

        searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }





}
class Food {
    var title: String?
    var image: UIImage?

    init(title: String?, image: UIImage?) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

here is code for collection view cell

```
class CategoriesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewCell: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoriesTitleLbl: UILabel!
}
```

How to avoid this program crash .and load the home page successfully .
you can download the project from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HPoFPdTOeKKpMEc_zdLGCGpjmgXe0HRb/view?usp=sharing
The error statement is

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UICollectionViewController 0x7f951651a340> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key collectionViewController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3c212b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109a56f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3c2079 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000109475a63 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010ac7f117 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010af70c2d -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3653cd -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010af6f5e3 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ac863ff -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ac86d2b -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010b5f6304 -[UICollectionViewController loadView] + 290
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ac8705c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010ac878b9 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b720441 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 89
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010ac542a3 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010ac9ab67 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3808
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010ac9d9a9 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 99
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010ac9e079 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 532
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010ac9d908 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 181
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010ac9dc67 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 159
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010aca2fea -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 274
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010b24fe9a __66-[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 134
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010b40fc1e -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 279
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010b40fad6 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010b40fd9e -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 157
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010aae0972 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010ac5fc3c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010ac5ff59 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010ac5ee86 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010ab56807 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2807
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010ab57f2a -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010aafb365 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010b447a1d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010b44a672 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a365101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a404f71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a349a6b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 267
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a348fff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a348889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    39  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001129509c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    40  UIKit                               0x000000010aadf5d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    41  WowPatient                          0x0000000108f70b47 main + 55
    42  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010eb87d81 start + 1
    43  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What's the crash? what appears on the log?

Comment: in Appdelegate.swift file class at line:  AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { .   .....The crash statement is . Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: Does it appears on the log? please mention what's generated in the log...

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UICollectionViewController 0x7f951651a340> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key collectionViewController.'

Comment: 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3c212b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109a56f41

Comment: 9   UIKit                               0x000000010ac86d2b -[UIViewController loadView] + 177..............error message is too long

Comment: Then add it in the question itself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your `CollectionViewController`

First, the class is inheriting from `UIViewController`, but your storyboard has a `UICollectionViewController`, modify `CollectionViewController.swift` file to inherit from `UICollectionViewController`, like so:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating
```

Add `override` keyword in the beginning these 2 methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

Edit your storyboard and remove the delegate and datasource references in connections inspector, also remove the IBOutlet reference

Now that `IBOutlet` is removed from storyboard, removed it from class as well

> @IBOutlet var collectionViewController: UICollectionView!

Now if you want to access your `UICollectionView`, just use `self.collectionView` instead of `self.collectionViewController`, like so:

```
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
self.collectionView?.dataSource = self
self.collectionView?.delegate = self
```

Update, add this in `class CategoriesCollectionViewCell`

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = .black
}
```

Comment: i have done these things you have mentioned program is not crashing but program is not giving the required home page in collection view .you can download the project from this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hQIyTcYUFkdzOXC5Kjhc23BCI-mE1Rka/view?usp=sharing.....how display the home page after pressing sign in button ?

Comment: Works for me, can you set backgroundColor to the cell, and remove `self.collectionView.register`, see my updated answer

Comment: Here are the changes that I suggested https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uMoocIDNOLERp7t97Pxfa2f_MDF1a8T8

Comment: Why images are not displayed collection view cell

Comment: Because you are using folder names as image, see `view appointments@1x.png` there isn't such an image, also you do NOT need @1x.png @2x.png part, just use the image base name without size class and extension, also its better to move your images in `Assets.xcassets` so that the right size of image will be picked automatically, to do this, select 3 files @1x @2x @3x of the same image and drag in `Assets.xcassets`

Comment: Like so `UIImage(named: "back")`, you do not need @1x.png @2x.png part

Answer (score 0):

Add numberOfSections method before numberOfItemsInSection.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Problem was here in both adding CollectionViewController and CategoriesCollectionViewCell]

Click to `Inherit Module From Target`. Problem was here in both adding CollectionViewController and CategoriesCollectionViewCell

And rename `collectionViewController` to `collectionView`

Comment: Try removing value of the field `Class` at all, and see in drop down you will not find `CategoriesCollectionViewController` as a choice anymore, because storyboard is `UICollectionViewController` and class is `UIViewController`

Comment: @AamirR I downloaded the app code, "Inherit Module From Target"  was not selected for CollectionViewController and CategoriesCollectionViewCell. I selected, then no problems occurred Because in the code there are CollectionViewController and CategoriesCollectionViewCell.